# S3 and semi-public bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I am doing some small devices running Debian. They need to sync a S3 bucket to a folder locally. I Have installed S3Tools and s3cmd sync seems to be the perfect tool. But I have to supply the Access Credentials and that seems VERY insecure. I will not be controlling the units once they ship so I need to somehow use the tool without supplying the credentials - AND I need to make sure the credentials can not delete in the bucket.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I go about this?

Regards, Jacob

Comment: You can make the bucket public for download and/or upload. But I'm not sure that you want do with your devices and what kind of security you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use IAM. It allows creation of AWS credentials with predefined permissions, which are under your control.

So you will create one identity per device. You are free to restrict access only to some buckets, keys.

You will not be able updating "device" credentials on your devices (this is simply your constrain), but in case some of your credentials will turn out as compromised, you still have the option to block it via IAM.

And for your primary "root" identity, I strongly recommend using two factor authentication (and of-course never put it to a device, you do not have control of).

Comment: This would potentially be quite a bit of overhead in managing IAM user accounts. Whether or not this is a viable answer depends on what type of security is needed.